# Why can't I use the password as the encryption key to securely encrypt a password?

Tags: encryption

I've read about how it is insecure to store encrypted passwords as someone who has access to your database/server can get hold of your encryption key and then get decrypt the users passwords. And the recommended way is using hash-salt method.

But what if I use the password as the key to encrypt itself?

For example (pseudocode) :

```
raw_pswrd = get_user_input_pswrd()
encrypted_pswrd = (text=raw_pswrd, key=raw_pswrd)
```

This way only the user that knows the the raw password has the ability to decrypt and validate it, just like the hash-salt method.

Why is this method not utilized or talked about as much as hash-salt? Does it have drawbacks?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638281/is-it-safe-to-encrypt-a-string-using-same-string-as-key

Comment: Good question, but I think this is more suited for Computer Science stack exchange

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to encrypt a string using same string as key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638281/is-it-safe-to-encrypt-a-string-using-same-string-as-key)

Comment: Well the title is similar but not the question and context

Comment: Your method is essentially an ad-hoc hashing method, and has all the drawbacks of any hashing method, namely: it is too fast (enabling brute force) and it is amenable to precomputation attacks (e.g. rainbow tables). You need iteration, salting, and algorithms that are unfavorable to GPU or ASIC implementation. In other words, something like argon2